# For loop not being entered

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm still working on my Java Diamond Problem.

Here is the current state of the diamond

[image: http://prntscr.com/2i9l9y]

I'm thinking the problem is the `for` loop right here,
all I need is for those spaces to be printed and then I'm finished.

Can anyone see any obvious reasons why the `for` loop I labeled with the problem isn't being entered or running?

```
//Bottom half of the diamond

    int middleSpaces = sides + 2;
    int downPreSpaces = 1;
    int dRows = sides + 1;

    for (int x = 1; x <= dRows; x++) {
        if (x >= dRows) {
            for (int z = 1; z <= sides + 1; z++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("v");
        }

        if (x != dRows) {

            for(int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print("\\");

        //PROBLEM IS HERE

            for (int e = middleSpaces - 2; e <= 0; e += 2) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print("/\n");
        }
```

Comment: Post the initial values for dRows,middlespace.etc

Comment: @boxed__l there you go, also I've just been messing with the stopping point for the loop, so I know it's not right whats in there right now, but if you could point me to the right variable to plug in that'd be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not decrementing `middleSpaces` also it was not initialized properly:

```
        int middleSpaces = sides * 2;   //NOTICE
        int downPreSpaces = 1;
        int dRows = sides + 1;    
        for (int x = 1; x <= dRows; x++) {
            if (x >= dRows) {
                for (int z = 1; z <= sides + 1; z++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("v");
            }    
            if (x != dRows) {    
                for(int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }    
                System.out.print("\\");    
                for (int e = middleSpaces - 2; e >= 0; e -= 1) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                middleSpaces-=2;   //NOTICE
                System.out.print("/\n");
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help, it seems simple now that I know what the problem was :) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Step through your code with a debugger and examine the state of the variables e and dRows at the location that is causing problems.

Comment: Ok ill ask it this way, What would you do to try and calculate the spaces needed in this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

middleSpaces - 2 might be less than dRows, or else one of the outer loops doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the values of dRows, middleSpaces and dmSpaces do not change in the code you've shown. This means the inner loop in question will always print the same number of spaces.

You probably mean something like the following:

```
for(int e = middleSpaces - 2; e >= x; e -= 2) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

That might be off by one or something but is closer to the result you're trying to get.

Comment: That did allow some spaces to be entered, however they're still off. For a 5 sized shape, Id need to print 9 spaces, then decrease by 2 each time after. I thought that loop would do that, but I guess I'm not writing it correctly.